# Cannot move Navigation Bar above tableview Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have added a table view controller that has a table view cell and when I try to add a navigation bar to the top. However when I try to add the navigation bar, it is not getting placed above the table view cell. I have tried it in both ways i.e. by trying to place it in the UI view (didn't work) and also in the Document Outline view (didn't work). Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong here? I have attached the screenshot for your reference.

Cheers.[image]

Comment: actually you were added the navigation bar to subview of tableview , remove from there and add to view hierarchy means layout in navigation bar and tableview

Comment: I already tried that, it doesn't accept my navigation bar without the tableview plus when I add the navigation bar without the table view cell its fine, but as soon as I add the tableview cell, it moves the navigation bar below the table view cell.

Comment: can you compress your project and give the link I will try

Comment: how do I share it with you?

Comment: compress your project and go to sendspace.com upload your project and take the link from there]

Comment: https://www.sendspace.com/file/1kqm9e

Comment: give only five minutes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the outline view, make sure your **Table View Controller** is selected.

Then go to the  **Editor** menu, and click on the **Embed In** submenu, and choose **Navigation Controller**. You have your navigation controller pointing to your tableview controller with a relationship built in.

[image]

Comment: else you go for UIviewcontroller (use navigation bar and UItableview )in this place of UItableviewcontroller

Comment: Let me give that a try and I'll get back to you.